# Expo-Dev-Client has a very poor performance on device

Tags: react-native, performance, expo, expo-dev-client

I am working on an application using Expo-Dev-Client. I downloaded it to my phone after doing extensive testing with the simulator. For some reason, it takes much longer to load images, icons, and other things when on my phone. Is there a solution? Or would it be better performance after it is published to the app stores?